# Ajax post to same page and reload the page without destroying the post parameters

Tags: php, ajax, post, post-parameter

Anyone knows how to preserve the post parameters after windows.location.reload(true) ?

```
function handler(event,ui)
{
  $(this).find(".thumb").remove();
  $(this).append('<img class="thumb" src="'+ui.draggable.attr('src')+'">');

  imageurl = ui.draggable.attr('src');

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'www.check.com.sg/', 
     data: {name: imageurl}, 
     complete:function(){
        window.location.reload(true);
     } 
  });
}
```

If i do a reload on the page. the post parameters will be destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep you can do it. Just put all your post variables in a hidden form on the page like this :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_var1" value="value_of_my_var1" />
    <!-- More inputs here.... -->
</form>
```

And then submit your form when your ajax call is done :

```
function handler(event,ui)
{
  $(this).find(".thumb").remove();
  $(this).append('<img class="thumb" src="'+ui.draggable.attr('src')+'">');

  imageurl = ui.draggable.attr('src');

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'www.check.com.sg/', 
     data: {name: imageurl}, 
     complete:function(){
        $('#myform').submit();
     } 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First your approach is wrong for AJAX; one shouldn't refresh the page after success instead use .html() or .load() method of jQuery.

Now if still you want to do the same then it can't be done using

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

instead use

```
window.location.href
```

So

```
function handler(event, ui) {
    $(this).find(".thumb").remove();
    $(this).append('<img class="thumb" src="' + ui.draggable.attr('src') + '">');
    imageurl = ui.draggable.attr('src');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'www.check.com.sg/',
        data: {
            name: imageurl
        },
        complete: function() {
            var currentURL = window.location.href + '?var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2;
            window.location.href = currentURL;
        }
    });
}
```